# change value at specific location in a tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df

`df = data.frame(col1=1:4, col2 = 5:8, col3 = 9:12)`

I want to change the value in row2, col2 to 44

In base R, I use `df["2","col2"] = 44`, how do I do this in tidyverse?

```
df = data.frame(col1=1:4, col2 = 5:8, col3 = 9:12)
df
df["2","col2"]=44
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = ifelse(row_number() == 2, 44, col2))

#>   col1 col2 col3
#> 1    1    5    9
#> 2    2   44   10
#> 3    3    7   11
#> 4    4    8   12
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the `rows_update()` function from `dplyr`?

```
rows_update(df, tibble(col1=2, col2=44))
```

---

```
# Matching, by = "col1"
# A tibble: 4 x 3
   col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5     9
2     2    44    10
3     3     7    11
4     4     8    12
```